# mongoose-text-search is not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a already built old project on nodejs where I am using MongoDb to store data. Mongodb version is 2.4

The problem is I am running a text-search on a collection but it's never return anything which means console.log(arguments); never get print anything

It's to inform you guys that I am able to run `db.socialposts.runCommand( "text", { search: "accessories",limit: 1 } )` on mongo terminal and getting results very fast

```
var options, search;

options = {
  limit: 1
};

search = 'accessories';

console.log(search);

SocialPost.textSearch(search, options, function(err, out) {
 console.log(arguments);
 return true;
});
```

It's Schema is 
    var schema;

```
schema = new mongoose.Schema({
entity_id: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true
},
social_id: {
  type: String,
  required: true
},
type: {
  type: String,
  required: true
},
app: {
  type: String,
  required: true
},
date: {
  type: Date,
  required: true
},
url: {
  type: String,
  required: true
},
post: {
  type: String
},
title: {
  type: String
},
image: {
  type: String
},
video: {
 type: String
},
hashtags: [String]
}, {
 strict: 'throw'
});
```

And Index is

```
schema.index({
  type: 1,
  social_id: 1
});

schema.index({
  type: 1,
  entity_id: 1,
  date: 1
});

schema.index({
  title: 'text',
  post: 'text'
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out, it was a problem with mongoose connection, when I was running query it's status was connecting not connected; so, I changed it into following and it worked.

```
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', function (err) {
      ItemModel.textSearch('D', function (err, output) {
        if (err)
          console.log(err);
        else
          console.log(output);
        mongoose.disconnect();
     });
    });
```